# Pull Sales Transactions Report CSV via the API

Tags: square, square-connect

Is it possible to pull down the Transactions CSV export from a Squareup Dashboard? Or at least replicate the data from the Connect `v1` or `v2` APIs?

[image]

I can see in the page HTML that it appears to be making a POST to the endpoint `/v2/reports/transactions.csv`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API for pulling a CSV. It should be fairly easy to use the [Transactions endpoints](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions) to list the transactions you are wanting and then export your data in the file type of choice

Comment: Yeah, I feared that was necessary. ListTransactions doesn't contain all of the fields contained in the CSV, so I'll probably have to use the v1 Payments endpoint instead.

Comment: yeah, you might need to use some combination of the two depending on what specifically you want.